# In IE8 only when user clicks anywhere on page the body font changes ?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, fonts

This is a strange one...

http://subzerostudio.com/Clients/diningwithhistory/coopershallmenus.html

Look at this URL in IE8, click anywhere in the body and the font in the left column changes..

Never seen anything like this before - how can I stop this?

Cheers!

Comment: any ideas at all would be hugely appreciated - can't find anything about this anywhere! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i disable javascript and refresh the page, this does not occur. I suspect it's something in your javascript doing this or the result of an error.

Which makes sense as I get a JS error when i hit the page,

```
  document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object (in dropdown.js, line 2 character 4)
```

Comment: I believe I've nailed it down slightly - There is a bit of jquery on the page ...  $('body').click(function() {
  $('#content-wrapper').fadeTo( 200, 1 );
    });
basically the popups on the right when they are up, you click anywhre in the body to fade it back to normal opacity. When i remove this click function the problem is gone, however obviously I need this click function here.... any workaround do you think?

Comment: "navbar" does not seem to exist on that page, so do you need to include dropdown.js here since that is where it's looking for that element and failing.

Comment: That JS I posted is found in js/gallery.js I think thats where the problem is maybe?

Comment: yeah I tried commenting out the dropdown.js call on the page but it still happens, I think it is definitely to do with the ('body').click ?

Comment: Seems buggy, doesnt work properly in IE (you have to click twice). So i would remove it and find a better lightbox that deals with this without any extra work.